# Undefined Pickle step (again)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, pickle

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282437/cucumber-pickle-factory-girl-given-a-returning-undefined-step - this post didn't help me a lot.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails' # 3.0.5
gem 'capybara' # 1.1.1
gem 'rspec-rails' # 2.6.1
gem 'cucumber-rails' # 1.0.5
gem 'database_cleaner'
gem 'factory_girl_rails' # 1.2.0
gem 'email_spec'
gem 'pickle' # 0.4.8
```

I do:

```
rails new pickle_test
bundle install
rails g cucumber:install
rails g rspec:install
rails g pickle --paths --email
rails g scaffold category title:string 
rake db:migrate
rake db:test:prepare
cucumber
```

I have:

```
$ cucumber
Using the default profile...
Feature: Manage categories

  Scenario: list existed categories                       # features/manage_categories.feature:3
    Given a category exists, title: "First category ever" # features/manage_categories.feature:4
      Undefined step: "a category exists, title: "First category ever"" (Cucumber::Undefined)
      features/manage_categories.feature:4:in `Given a category exists, title: "First category ever"'
    When I go to the categories page                      # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:48
    Then I should see "First category ever"               # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:105

1 scenario (1 undefined)
3 steps (2 skipped, 1 undefined)
0m0.127s

You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

Given /^a category exists, title: "([^"]*)"$/ do |arg1|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

Note that I did nothing to configure this test app anyhow and I don't use factory_girl or anything rather then ActiveRecord. I'm confident it should work from there. Pickle itself is loaded (tested with puts), cucumber runs using environments/test.rb.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your step def is not using the correct phraseology.

The default Pickle steps (you should feel free to adapt them to your app/style) expect the following:

Given a category exists with title: "First category ever"

Cheers,
Ian

Comment: Sorry for belated feedback. It says the same even I follow the guide: You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

Given /^a category exists with title: "([^"]*)"$/ do |arg1|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

Comment: Question is closed - problem was in FactoryGirl.